# Can't export SQL files

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem with exporting SQL files. When I click go it just opens the sql file with notepad, here's a pic:

[image]

The (9) shows how many times i've downloaded the file. I also can't see the file on my downloads folder.

Comment: Use "Save" instead of "Open"?

Comment: Or deassociate the MIME type from opening in Notepad per default?

Comment: @maio290 Still the same, can't open the file and I can't see it on Downloads folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a problem with your phpmyadmin , please try use cmd or terminal to export all your databases and reinstall phpmyadmin again. This might fix the issue. To export using cmd or terminal use code below:

You should use mysqldump, since it tries to do the data dump without blocking the database tables.
`mysqldump -u [username] -p [database-you-want-to-dump] > [path-to-place-data-dump]`

So it could be something like this:

`mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > /home/myuser/database-dump.sql`

Comment: " 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. " show me error

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting SQL dumps in notepad then you are actually getting the SQL dump. I think only problem is you cant find the downloaded file because you must have specified different folder for saving downloaded files. Check your browser settings. Press Ctrl+J to see the recent downloads. Or easiest is copy that open notepad contents to new file and save as you want.

Comment: Yes, I think this might be the case. How do I fix the SQL dump? I tried researching about it but I can't seem to understand it, I might need some of your help. Also is it ok if I just copy the contents of the notepad and save it to .sql? will that work?

Comment: Normally it should be fine if you do not change the contents of the downloaded file. I assume you are using default settings of PhpMyAdmin to export the file otherwise it has many different export choices including CVS and XLS etc.,

Answer (score 0):

The big question here is: Do you want to solve your problem and not just workaround it with console?

I really think this is a windows/browser problem - not a PHPMyAdmin problem.

Looking at the line you have in that Notepad - I see bits of SQL for table creation and column data in your screenshot.  It looks like a working dump.  Your notepad view is very wide - most of the  data is cut off.

On Notepad- `Format->Word Wrap` and compare it with a console dump.  *I have a feeling both files will be identical*.

Next step - what browser are you using?

If you're using Chrome, you can go into settings and have it ask where to save the file before downloading (This setting:  "Ask where to save each file before downloading").    That will let you switch the download location from your `%appdata%/roaming` to wherever you want.

Apparently - [in the current version of Chrome, this setting will stop auto-opening](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Q4tySQhvnG0).

Once you try getting that setting turned on ... try turning it off.  It may just clear your problem as it did for the poster in the Chrome product forum.